# Как узнать размер файла по НЕ прямой ссылке в PHP?

Tags: php

Есть ссылка на файл `/download?docId=123`
По ссылке срабатывает код, который ищет запись файла в базе, потом в базе смотрит есть ли он, если есть то получает путь к фалу, если нет то генерирует новый файл из шаблона.

Мне нужно посмотреть размер файла по ссылке `/download?docId=123`. Как это сделать?

Функций `filesize()` ругается на этот путь. Но если мы перейдем по этой ссылке, то начнется скачивание.

То-есть для получения размера файла придется обять сбегать в базу, если нет файла, то сгенерировать, положить на диск, потом по пути на диске получить размер через filesize()?

Или все же можно получить размер из непрямой ссылки типа `/download?docId=123` ?

Comment: по такой сссылке вы получите размер только скачав файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный URL вы открываете, и он качается. 
В теории, можно сделать HEAD-запрос на него и посмотреть потом на полученный заголовок Content-Length.

Вот тут - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2773408/2822609, как раз про это говорили.
Ho, повторюсь, тут нужно проверять. Если система самописная, не факт, что она обработает ваш запрос.

Comment: вот что-то мне подсказывает, что  человеку надо вывести ссылку на скачивание, а рядом размер файла для информации. И делать  для этого http-запрос кажется весьма большим костылем.

Comment: @teran, я написал о теоретической возможности получения информации - есть метод HEAD, который в теории может получить данную информацию. Согласен с Вашим предложением, если есть возможность использовать размер файла без обращения к самому ресурсу - лучше так и поступить. Поскольку, даже head-запрос запустит цепочку, которая обратится к ресурсу, подсчитает его размер и отдаст его в заголовке (в идеале, а ведь может и вообще не обработать)

Comment: суть моего комментария была, в том, что обращаться к самому же себе через внешний http-запрос это несколько странно. Ваш ответ подойдет для варианта с внешним ресурсом. Но тут не ясно вообще, какой ресурс, но мне кажется. что свой. Просто у человека файл еще не сгенерирован, а размер ему нужен.